# Why can I wake-on-lan the computer from sleep but not from shutdown?

Tags: windows-7, wake-on-lan

On my [Shuttle SZ77R5](http://data.shuttle.eu/CeBIT/en_sz77r5.html), running Windows 7x64, I have enabled wol in the bios and on the network card in Device Manager.  I am trying to wol (wake-on-lan) the computer from another Windows7x64 machine.

I've tried [Matcode's wol application](http://www.matcode.com/wol.htm), [Depicus's wolcmd](http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-cmd.aspx), and a few others, and they will wake up the computer if it is *asleep* but not if it has been *shutdown* using the software shutdown command.

My question is why I can't wol a computer that is shut down (except with Softperfect Network Scanner)?

I've read [this thread to no avail](https://serverfault.com/questions/410784/wake-on-lan-wol) about wol.
I've read a bunch of guides on how to do this, and am positive I've got all the settings correct.  Here are some links:

- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/trigger-wake-lan-mac-address/
- https://secure.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WOL#Automatic_Wake-On-LAN_Daemon
- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/turn-pc-android-phone-wakeonlan/

Comment: Hmmm... My question just got migrated from ServerFault - I thought ServerFault was for networking questions.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your nic isn't staying on when the machine is "off".

**1)** Check to see if the network activity LEDs are active when the machine is powered down.

**2)** Check your BIOS settings. There may well be a WoL setting in there you've got turned off.

**3)** It's remotely possible your issue is with your network fabric, outside of your computer. You could try a test of connecting a crossover cable between your machine and another you have, send the WoL signal that way, if there's a difference, it would seem your switch or something may be factoring some how.

Comment: 1- No, there aren't any lights.  It's a slim DIY mini-box, so I'm not surprised.  2. I can't find that setting if there is one.  3. Softperfect netscan CAN do it but wolcmd can't.

Comment: Also, the only thing between the two computers is a little switch.

Comment: Try directly connecting the computers. If the switch is somehow the issue, you can rule it out with a direct connection. Hence my third suggestion.